# Selenium WebDriver: How to select a value in a span dropdown?

Tags: java, html, selenium

I'm trying to get my Selenium script to click on a value within a dropdown menu. However I am having trouble getting any action to happen within the dropdown after I initially clicked it. I have looked online and can only find answers if the dropdown was 'Select.'

Here is the HTML for the dropdown:

```
<span class="select2-selection__rendered" title="1st item"
      id="select2-id_template_or_inspection-container">
</span>
```

Here is the code snippet where I click on the dropdown:

```
//Choose a Template from Dropdown

WebElement dropdownBtn = webDriver.findElement(
            By.id("select2-id_template_or_inspection-container"));

dropdownBtn.click();
```

Here is the code snippet where I try to click on a value in the dropdown:

```
WebElement dropdownItemBtn = webDriver
      .findElement(By.id("select2-id_template_or_inspection-result-hlwt-tmpl-2583"));
dropdownItemBtn.click();
```

However the IDs for the values in the dropdown change each time the page is reloaded.

I appreciate the help!

Comment: Please create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that includes the script you're using to try and accomplish this task. Also tag the language your script is written in if necessary.

Comment: thanks! I have updated the question

Comment: Can you also include the URL this dropdown is located at? If the IDs change then you will have to try to select the element using something else, such as by CSS selector.

Comment: @Long,  A dropdown includes options at least, your given HTML code not includes HTML code of options list.  Please find out them and update in question (not in comment).  If you can't find them, please give a public URL if your app have. Or you know your dropdown is some know plugin, lie jQuery dropdown plugin.

Comment: Could you please confirm that, span tag id is completely changed each time or some part is constant?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this approach:

1. This is what you did, to click on span to reveal its dropdown items

   ```
   //Choose a Template from Dropdown

   WebElement dropdownBtn = webDriver.findElement(By.id("select2-id_template_or_inspection-container"));
   dropdownBtn.click();
   ```
2. Because the IDs for the values in the dropdown are changed each time the page is reloaded, so you can use `dropdownBtn` to look for its child/children as dropdown items and click on the dropdown you want:

   ```
   List<WebElement> dropdownItems = dropdownBtn.findElements(By.tagName("tagNameOfDropdownItems"));
   dropdownItems.get(0).click(); // click on first Dropdown, for example
   ```

Because IDs are changed dynamically, so let's try to find elements by `tagName`. Hope it helps.